# how to lag columns in batch in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with more then 100 columns. i need to lag 60 of them, and i know columns names for which i need to lag. Is there a way to lag them in batch or just few lines? 
Say I have a dataframe like belwo

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 ... col100
 1     2   3     4   5   6         8
 3     9   15    19  21  23        31
```

The only way i know is to do it one by one. i.e run `df['col1_lag']=df['col'].shift(1)` for each column.

It seems too much for so many columns. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for new DataFrame and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df1 = df.join(df.shift().add_suffix('_lag'))
#alternative
#df1 = pd.concat([df, df.shift().add_suffix('_lag')], axis=1)
print (df1)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col100  col1_lag  col2_lag  col3_lag  \
0     1     2     3     4     5     6       8       NaN       NaN       NaN   
1     3     9    15    19    21    23      31       1.0       2.0       3.0   

   col4_lag  col5_lag  col6_lag  col100_lag  
0       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN  
1       4.0       5.0       6.0         8.0
```

If want lag only some columns is possible filter them by `list`:

```
cols = ['col1','col3','col5']
df2 = df.join(df[cols].shift().add_suffix('_lag'))
print (df2)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col100  col1_lag  col3_lag  col5_lag
0     1     2     3     4     5     6       8       NaN       NaN       NaN
1     3     9    15    19    21    23      31       1.0       3.0       5.0
```